# Square of summation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble trying to expand this summation:

$$\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |X_{\frac{i}{n}}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}}|^p|X_{\frac{i+1}{n}}-X_{\frac{i}{n}}|^q\Bigg)^2$$

I am trying to use the following without luck

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}y_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(x_{i}y_{i}\right)^{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i\neq j}^{n-1}x_{i}y_{i}x_{j}y_{j}$$

Comment: What does it mean that the subscripts are divided by $n$?

Comment: It is a way to normalize the observations such that they range from [0,1] for the observations i=0,1,...,n